# cannot find by id in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have problem with query in MongoDB.

I have document with that structure

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("5eca9329-6525-e544-bb27-f1797def8110"),
    "StartTimestamp" : NumberLong(193),
    "EndTimestamp" : NumberLong(193),
}
```

_id is generate from GUID (C#). And the problem is when i want do native query in mongo console.

My query

```
db.getCollection('Object').findOne(
{
    "_id": LUUID("5eca9329-6525-e544-bb27-f1797def8110")
})
```

And then i have non result

Comment: There is not "LUUID" datatype in MongoDB. What BSON type does the C# driver use to represent this type? You can check that in the mongodb shell by getting the next-best document with `db.getCollection('Object').findOne()`. I suspect it's either converted to a string or an object-representation of your C# LUUID class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo's support for GUID is limited at the moment. C# drivers are currently writing GUIDs in a binary representation where the first three fields of the GUID are little endian , whereas some other drivers are using the big endian representation. So depending on which driver stored the GUID the string representation would be different, see this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3153) ticket for further detail,

In short, as your GUID is created by C#, it is stored as a BinData object with type 3 as shown below.

```
BinData(3,"KZPKXiVlROW7J/F5fe+BEA==")
```

This means that in order to retrieve your record, you will have to run the following query:

```
db.getCollection('Object').findOne(
{
   "_id": BinData(3,"KZPKXiVlROW7J/F5fe+BEA==")
})
```

Alternatively you can load the helper script from [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js)  when starting a Mongo shell:

```
mongo --shell uuidhelpers.js
```

When this is loaded you can query for your GUID like this:

```
db.data.find({_id:CSUUID("5eca9329-6525-e544-bb27-f1797def8110")})
```